# iPhone - file properties

Tags: iphone, uitableview, nsfilemanager

i m creating an application which makes the iphone work as a pendrive for easy file sharing purpose.

In the first stage, i have some files(png, pdf, jpg, zip) in a directory and i made them display in the tableview in the form of mutable array. It displays in the tableView as shown below,

```
.DS_Store
.localized
gazelle.pdf
Hamburger_sandwich.jpg
IITD TAJ Picture 028_jpg.jpg
iya_logo_final_b&w.jpg
manifesto09-eng.pdf
RSSReader.sql
SimpleURLConnections.zip
SQLTutorial
```

I just want to display the name of the files and i do not want to display the extensions. I know that it is possible to extract the extensions of a file in NSFileManager. But i do not know how. Please help me to make my table view look like this

```
.DS_Store
.localized
gazelle
Hamburger_sandwich
IITD TAJ Picture 028_jpg
iya_logo_final_b&w
manifesto09-eng
RSSReader
SimpleURLConnections
SQLTutorial
```

In the second stage i have a detailedViewController which takes displays the detailed view of the file like

1. file size
2. file type
3. if it is a image, it should open in imageView
4. if it is a song, it should play it

So i need to retrive the properties like filePath, fileType, fileSize.. of each files. Please guide me with a tutorial if possible. I too do not have any idea how to convert a mutableArray to a NSString and call the methods like stringByDeletingPathExtension. Please help me. I can even send my source code if needed. If possible, guide me with some example codes and tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:)
This will get all files in a directory in a NSString *parentDirectory, get its size, if image do something otherwise it assumes is a sound file

```
NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *filePaths = [fm contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:parentDirectory error:&error];
if (error) {
    NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
    error = nil;
}   
for (NSString *filePath in filePaths) {
    //filename without extension
    NSString *fileWithoutExtension = [[filePath lastPathComponent] stringByDeletingPathExtension];

    //file size
    unsigned long long s = [[fm attributesOfItemAtPath:[parentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:filePath] 
                                  error:NULL] fileSize];

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:[parentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:filePath];];
    //if image...
    if(image){
        //show it here
    }
    else{
        //otherwise it should be music then, play it using AVFoundation or AudioToolBox
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope you will have the file name in NSURL object, if so then you can use the following code to get just the file name and can remove the file extension from the string.

```
NSArray *fileName = [[fileURL lastPathComponent] componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
NSLog(@"%@",[fileName objectAtIndex:0]);
```

Comment: No yar. I have the Files in the document directory. I am not using the url at all. I need to display the contents in my directory in the tableView without the file extensions.. Thank u for the reply..