# iPhone - properties of a file

Tags: iphone, filesize, nsfilemanager, file-type

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iPhone - file properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4134618/iphone-file-properties)

Hi all. i m creating an application which makes the iphone work as a pendrive for easy file sharing purpose.

In the first stage, i have some files(png, pdf, jpg, zip) in a directory and i made them display in the tableview in the form of mutable array without the extensions of each file.

In the second stage i have a detailedViewController which then displays the detailed view of the files like

1. file size
2. file type
3. if it is a image, it should open in imageView
4. if it is a song, it should play it

So i need to retrieve the properties like filePath, fileType, fileSize.. of each files. Now i got stuck in getting those properties like fileSize and fileType... Please help me proceed with a sample source code.

Here is my code.

```
- (void)listFiles {

NSFileManager *fm =[NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSError *error = nil;
NSString *parentDirectory = @"/Users/akilan/Documents";
NSArray *paths = [fm contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:parentDirectory error:&error];
if (error) {
    NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
    error = nil;
}
directoryContent = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (NSString *path in paths){
    documentsDirectory = [[path lastPathComponent] stringByDeletingPathExtension];
    NSLog(@"%@", documentsDirectory);
    [directoryContent addObject:documentsDirectory];

}
```

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use the method `attributesOfItemAtPath:error:` of your filemanager instance.
Have a look at the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000305-SW8).

Comment: ok. when i use the method attributesOfItemAtPath:error:, it displays the available particulars of the each file in the console. How can i retrieve a particular detail of a particular file? For example, I need the date of creation of the second file.. How can i get it?